# Extracting the year from UNIX timestamps in R, using only the base package

Tags: r, lubridate

I can use the following code to extract the year from unix timestamps:

```
# Unix timestamps: 1500000000, 1400000000

as.numeric(format(as.POSIXct(c(1500000000, 1400000000), origin = "1970-01-01"), "%Y"))

# [1] 2017 2014
```

But this seems like a long line of code for a simple task.

Can we write a shorter line of code to do get the years in the numeric format without using any additional packages like `lubridate`?

Comment: For base R, this is already pretty concise.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want the years in the numeric format.  Is the edited code still concise?

Comment: Yes. It only looks verbose because you supplied two "large looking" arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `POSIXct`, convert to `POSIXlt` and take the `year` component:

```r
as.POSIXlt(c(1500000000, 1400000000), origin="1970-01-01")$year + 1900
```